# Can't add controller of model that inherits from other class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, inheritance

I'm using Entity Framework and MVC3, and my problem is that I can't scaffold Controllers if the Model inherits from another Class.

Example:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class User : Person
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> PersonSet { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to Add the Controller `User` using template `Controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework` I get this error:

> 'User' is not part of the specified 'Context' class, and the 'Context' class could not be modifed to add a 'DbSet' property to it. (For example, the 'Context' class might be in a compiled assembly.)

I could add `public DbSet<User> UserSet { get; set; }` to the `Context` but I don't think it is the right aproach.

Comment: If you don't add User to DbContext, where are you going to store Email and Password?

Comment: By adding just the PersonSet to Context I can get a list of Users by doing `context.PersonSet.OfType<User>()`

Comment: @vicentedealencar , I am facing the same error, how do you solved this ? This is my issue [MyQuestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720611/cant-add-controller-which-uses-class-which-is-inherited-from-other-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment your `User` is not persisted type because context doesn't know that type so you cannot use scaffolding of persisted entity types to create controller for `User` type. If you want to store `User` and its properties in database add this to your context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>();
}
```

If you don't want to persist  `User` to database you cannot use scaffolding for controller creation.

Comment: What's the difference between this and defining public DbSet<User> UserSet { get; set; } in DbContext?

Comment: The set is public property exposed on the context. This is just mapping provided to context but the result in both operation is the same - context knows about the User entity.

Comment: That's what I thought. But I just can't think of a reason why would someone prefer defining a mapping without exposing it as a property. Personally, I'd rather use a property to access a set than generic methods.